# Library to send/receive push notifications for desktop applications

Tags: windows, c#, desktop-client, notification

I am looking for a library that can be easily integrated into a Windows desktop application and enables it to receive push notifications. Not only for Windows 8 but for 7 and Vista as well.

Preferably the library is written in C# and supports WinForms.

Comment: Notifications are always bound to specific server service.  [Example.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service) Or MS Exchange. Do you have idea from which service you wish to receive the notifications?